# Resistor right at the output of op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors

I am puzzled by the use of these resistors R227 R228 and R210 in the non-inverting amplifier circuit below:

[image]

My spice simulation does not allow me to understand the use of R227, the only thing I notice is that the voltage before it at node 6 is slightly above the voltage after it, which is to be expected, I still find the expected gain for the op amp.

R228 I think is meant to make the line look like a 50 Ohm line, is that correct?

R210 is probably for some kind of protection?

These are my best guesses. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this **not** an existing circuit in a real-world physical product (ie: just a simulation or a prototype one-off), then **Answer #1** applies, otherwise, please refer to **Answer #2**.

**Answer #1: simulation or prototype**
It is good practice to place resistors in locations R227, R210 & R228, and then finalise their values during testing.  These resistors become increasingly important as signal frequency increases, and will affect:
(a) output voltage at the connector J205 vs the output at opamp pin 6.
(b) how external voltages appearing at J205 affect the opamp.
(c) how J205 behaves at high frequency, eg: transmission line effects.
(d) stability of the opamp.
(e) gain (output vs input) in the intended signal range.  For example, the intended function of R210 may be as a gain-trimming resistor, perhaps.

Behaviour under fault conditions may also be a consideration.  For example, R228, R210, R224 affect (define) the impedance appearing at J205 if the opamp is either not loaded, or its output stage has failed (blown open-circuit).

There is also the protection of the opamp to consider, for example, if J205 is shorted, or is connected to a high voltage, or is connected to a load the opamp does not like, eg: a capacitor of high value.

Some folk also place an additional resistor from opamp output to feedback network, ie: pin 6 to R224 in this case, and may add an additional R from R224 to the join of R227 & R228.  This allows the load at J205 to be further decoupled from the opamp output and the feedback point, all of which become more important as the intended signal frequency increases.

If testing reveals these are not needed, then in the limiting case R227 & R228 go to zero ohms, and R210 goes to infinity (open circuit, or not loaded).

**Answer #2: An Existing Product**
R227 limits the current in/out of pin 6, so protects the opamp, while the feedback point at the join of R227-R228 allows the opamp output to swing higher to keep the voltage at J205 closer to the intended value, at least for small signals (eg: before pin 6 hits supply-rail limits).

R228 being close to 50 ohms is a fairly standard approach to having a transmission line termination at J205, although this is probably misguided in this case, since R228 is not tied to an effective "RF short-circuit".

If the designer applied the thinking explained in Answer #1 above, then these are probably the values that were in place when the circuit was tested, and when testing was finished these were left unchanged when it went into production, regardless of whether or not they are required for the intended application.  The pace of electronic design, the short product market lifetime, and the lower component costs these days, all mean that the time spent in design & testing is quite expensive compared to the cost of a couple of resistors, which may explain why R210, in particular, was loaded rather than being left as "DNL".